# parse_ini_file data is always 1

Tags: php

I try to parse a ini file to load PHP classes from it but whenever parse_ini_file parses the file, the variable that holds the content is always only "1".
Here is my code:

```
private $plugins = array();

public function __construct() {
    Logger::log("Loading plugins");
    Logger::debug("Loading " . APP_ROOT . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "config" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "plugins.ini");
    if (file_exists(APP_ROOT . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "config" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "plugins.ini")) {
        $data = parse_ini_file(APP_ROOT . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "config" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "plugins.ini", true);
        foreach ($data as $k => $d) {

            if (class_exists($k)) {
                $plugin = $this->createPlugin($k);
                if ($plugin instanceof Plugin) {
                    $this->init($plugin, $d);
                } else {
                    Logger::error("Plugin doesn't implements interface Plugin");
                }
            } else {
                Logger::error("Can't load plugin $k");
            }
        }
    } else {
        Logger::error(APP_ROOT . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "config" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "plugins.ini doesn't exists");
    }
}

public function createPlugin($name) {
    $plugin = unserialize(
            sprintf(
                    'O:%d:"%s":0:{}', strlen($name), $name
            )
    );

    return $plugin;
}

public function init(Plugin $plugin, $data) {
    try {
        Logger::log("Adding plugin " . get_class($plugin));
        Logger::debug("Calling init");
        $plugin->init($data);
        $this->plugins[get_class($plugin)] = $plugin;
    } catch (PluginException $ex) {
        Logger::error("Error while init plugin");
    }
}
```

The ini file:

```
[\eBot\Plugins\Official\MissionChecker]
url=http://someurl
```

I tried to add a log message after

```
foreach ($data as $k => $d) {
```

But this line was never called, therefore $data must be empty, buw how is that possible?
var_dump and print_r($data) show me "1".

Comment: Are you sure that you ini file format is ok?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by putting the url in the ini file in quotes.

```
[\eBot\Plugins\Official\MissionChecker]
url="http://someurl"
```